# If Android standard Alarm app rings - then

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentfilter, android-alarms

Is it possible for me to receive an Intent if the standard Application sounds an alarm?

So - I set my alarm for 8pm. It's 8pm now, so my phone rings. I see the typical X or zzZ buttons.
NOW my application should do something for me.

I know I could theoretically check the current Alarms and check when the next alarm is due and send a pending intent. Then I will have to manage the editing of alarms though.
Any Ideas? Thanks a ton.
Alex